# Difference in dates in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing the following query

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(data_elaborazione, 'YYYYMMDD') -  
    TO_DATE(DATA_INS_AGG_SDS, 'YYYYMMDD') )AS DateDiff
FROM
    dual
```

I want to calculate the difference between the two dates, in days, but I get an error:

> ORA-00904: "DATA_INS_AGG_SDS": invalid identifier

The same goes for `data_elaborazione` too. `Data_elaborazione`, `DATA_INS_AGG_SDS` are both `varchar` types that contain dates as `varchar`

Comment: `dual` doesn't have those columns.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Because the table that i am working on has dates as  strings. Don ask why even me i dunno why.

Comment: @dimmik, how the data is stored has nothing to do with your attempted math.  If you want a datediff, you need two dates, not a date and a string.

Comment: @DanBracuk - the OP's code *is* subtracting one date from another; the `to_char()` is around the resulting number, for some reason....

Comment: Why are you storing dates in a VARCHAR column? Don't do that.

Comment: @AlexPoole It is because the result of that query is about to be stored in a varchar column

Comment: So you're storing numbers as strings, as well as dates? Why aren't you using the correct data types in your tables? (You should also be using varchar2 rather than varchar really, but that's a minor issue by comparison...)

Comment: As stated by Gordon as well the error is because `dual` doesn't have those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is cause by you referencing columns on dual that do not exist.  You'll need to select these columns from the tables they actually exist in.  As for your date arithmetic, it should return a number, which does not require TO_CHAR to display, unless you have some specific formatting concerns.  Here is an example of date arithmetic.  The second date value has a time component.  So, the two columns due the date arithmetic and display the result, the second essentially rounds down to just get the number of days to an even integer value.

Please read the comments about data types.  You should always work with values in their correct data types.  Avoid storing either dates or numbers as strings in the DB.

```
-- start test_data
with some_data(begin_date, end_date) as
  (select to_date('02/15/2017','MM/DD/YYYY'), to_date('04/03/2017 09:34:12','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual)
-- end test data
select end_date - begin_date as num_days_diff_w_time,
       FLOOR(end_date - begin_date) as num_days_diff_wo_time
  from some_data;
```